# Trying to delete a row in a table based on cell value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to delete a row in a table in jquery.
each row has a check box as its first cell. 
On clicking delete button , it should delete only rows whose checkbox is checked. Following is the code I am trying

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
        var tableData = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var tabId = '#' + tableID + ' tr';
        var rowcount = $(tabId).length;         
        for ( var i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
            var chkbox = $(tableIDAct).children('td').eq(0).is(':checked');
                if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox) {
                    tableData.deleteRow(i);
                    rowcount--;
                    i--;
                }
        }
    }
```

Here I am not been able to iterate table by rows.
Suggest me 
Thanks

Comment: what is `tableIDAct` ?

Comment: tableIDAct and .deleteRow() are both invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably the problem is that you are checking `is(':checked')` on `td` objects instead of inputs

```
var chkbox = $(tabId).eq(i)
    .children('td').eq(0)
    .children('input[type=checkbox]')
    .is(':checked');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9fr2x93k/

Comment: In the above link its working fine but in my code it is saying tableData.deleteRow(i) is not a function. So is there any dependency

Comment: I only added jQuery; please notice that you declared the function as `function deleteRow` and I changed it to `var deleteRow = function`, and I put it in the `<script>` tag within `<body>`

Comment: also, I changed your `$(tableIDAct)` to `$(tabId).eq(i)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have use for this

```
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
```

you can delete one by one

```
   <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell 3</td>
        <td>cell 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br> 

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
    }
    </script>
```

If more details then

http://mrbool.com/how-to-add-edit-and-delete-rows-of-a-html-table-with-jquery/26721